# Add percentage (%) for a PieChart

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Hello guys i am trying to do a pie chart like the next picture:
But i am getting a lot of problem

[image]

But this is the plot that I am getting:

```
ggpie(s, x="costes", label ="prop", lab.pos = "in", fill = "Implementation",
  lab.font = list(size= 5)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue2","blue"))
```

How i could add percentage to my labels like 98.9%...etc

data:
`structure(list(Implementation = c("2", "1"), costes = c(6204670582.33,  70561379.07), prop = c(98.9, 1.1), lab.ypos = c(49.45, 99.45)), row.names = c(NA,  -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

**Thanks so much for your time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
per <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)
labels <- c("a","b","c","d")
pie(per,labels = paste0(labels," (",round(per,digits = 3)*100,"%)"),
    border="white",col = c("red","green","blue","yellow"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add with 'labels = '. I named your data dummy.

```
> dummy
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Implementation      costes  prop lab.ypos
  <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2              6204670582.  98.9     49.4
2 1                70561379.   1.1     99.4



dummy %>%
  ggpie(x="costes", label ="prop", lab.pos = "in", fill = "Implementation",
        lab.font = list(size= 5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue2","blue"), 
                    labels = paste(dummy$Implementation, (dummy$prop)))
```

[image: PieChart]